# Hacer un csv con pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

como estan todos? Espero que bien. Les comento, tengo un problema al querer hacer un csv con pandas y python. La cuestion es que yo quiero decirle que el "pais1", posee un nombre("Argentina") y que asu vez por see provincias ("p1,p2,p3,p4,p5") y asi con todas.
Adjunto archivo csv:

```
Numero,Nombre,provincias
Pais1,Argentina,p1,p2,p3,p4,p4,p5
Pais2,Brasil,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10
Pais3,Chile,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que el programa no me tome en la columna de provincias a solo p1 e ignore al resto. Quiero que entienda que ("p1,p2,p3,p4,p5") pertenecen a la columna provincias. Como hago eso?

Comment: al ser el `.csv` delimitado por comas no podras, puedes especificar otra delimitacion o cambiar el delimitador de las provincias, ejemplo `p1-p2-p3-p4...`

Comment: Se puede conservar el delimitador y encerrar entre `""` las columnas que contienen comas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dije la mejor forma es cambiar el delimitador, ya sea el delimitador de campos o el delimitador de datos (provincia)

**Cambiando delimitador de cvs**
Para esto, vamos a cambiar el delimitador a un punto y coma (`;`), así:

```
Numero;Nombre;provincias
Pais1;Argentina;p1,p2,p3,p4,p4,p5
Pais2;Brasil;p6,p7,p8,p9,p10
Pais3;Chile;p11,p12,p13,p14,p15
```

Y para leerlo, hacemos lo mismo que haria con `.csv` *normal*, además dado que tienes una columna `Numero`, la vamos a usar como índice.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('archivo.csv', delimiter=";", index_col='Numero')

#convertimos a DF
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

#obtenemos el campo provincias y lo convertimos a una lista
provincias = df['provincias'].to_list()
print(provincias)

#salida -> ['p1,p2,p3,p4,p4,p5', 'p6,p7,p8,p9,p10', 'p11,p12,p13,p14,p15']
```

**Cambiando delimitador del campo `provincias`**
Podemos usar cualquier carácter que no sea la coma (`,`), de preferencia algún carácter especial como un guion (`-`), barra (`|`), en este caso usare el guion (`-`)

**archivo.csv**

```
Numero,Nombre,provincias
Pais1,Argentina,p1-p2-p3-p4-p4-p5
Pais2,Brasil,p6-p7-p8-p9-p10
Pais3,Chile,p11-p12-p13-p14-p15
```

Y lo usamos de la misma forma, pero sin indicar el delimitador, que por defecto es la coma `,`

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('archivo.csv', index_col='Numero')

#convertimos a DF
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

#obtenemos el campo provincias y lo convertimos a una lista
provincias = df['provincias'].to_list()
print(provincias)
```

**Salida**

```
['p1-p2-p3-p4-p4-p5', 'p6-p7-p8-p9-p10', 'p11-p12-p13-p14-p15']
```

Si no tienes problemas puedes trabajar así, pero igual existe una forma de cambiar la separación, podemos usar la función `replace()` para indicarle que reemplace el guion (`-`) por una coma (`-`)

```py
provincias = df['provincias'].to_list()

#usamos una compresion de lista para cambiarlo
provincias = [provincia.replace('-',',') for provincia in provincias]
print(provincias)
```

Dando como resultado lo que queremos

```
['p1,p2,p3,p4,p4,p5', 'p6,p7,p8,p9,p10', 'p11,p12,p13,p14,p15']
```

Ahora si ya puedes trabajar con los datos. Si tienes alguna duda o problema avísame y tratare de ayudarte :)

Comment: Hola capo gracias!! Me ayudo tu solución aunque me ahorre una linea que era la de convertir a DF ya que al poner "pd.read_csv" ya se entiende que es un dataframe por lo que tengo entendido

Comment: Siempre respondes mis preguntas, hay alguna forma de conctactarte por otro medio? (Instagram, WhatsApp, Mail)

Comment: Bueno si, pero igual lo pongo ya al convertirlo a un DF ya se puede trabajar con ese tipo de dato, lo cual no seria igual que trabajar con un excel o txt, perfiro convertirlo a DF como un estandar :)

Comment: Bueno si, pero la vez pasada que puse mi gmail me borraron los comentarios

Comment: Únete al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124840/hola)!

Answer (score 0):

La solución más utilizada con archivos CSV, cuando hay datos que contienen el delimitador es encerrarlos entre comillas dobles; ya que esto puede pasar con cualquier delimitador.

Si tu archivo tiene este contenido:

```
Numero,Nombre,provincias
Pais1,Argentina,"p1,p2,p3,p4,p4,p5"
Pais2,Brasil,"p6,p7,p8,p9,p10"
Pais3,Chile,"p11,p12,p13,p14,p15"
```

Puedes simplemente:

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"c:\test\csv\paises.csv")
print(df);
```

Lo que produce la salida:

```
  Numero     Nombre           provincias
0  Pais1  Argentina    p1,p2,p3,p4,p4,p5
1  Pais2     Brasil      p6,p7,p8,p9,p10
2  Pais3      Chile  p11,p12,p13,p14,p15
```

Según la documentación de *[read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)*, puedes definir el comportamiento de la rutina, en cuanto a las comillas, valiéndote de parámetros como:

- `quotechar='"'`
- `quoting=0`
- `doublequote=True`
- `escapechar=None`

Que te servirán también para poder incluir comillas dentro de una columna que ya está encerrada entre comillas. Para más información, lee la documentación referenciada (en inglés).